# Is there a way to integrate webrtc application with messenger (Skype, hangouts, telegram, etc)

Tags: webrtc, messenger, peer

I'm looking to integrate a webrtc application with the famous messengers (Skype, hangouts, telegram etc).  Is there a way to do it?